# nginx 1.14.2 docker bad gateway respone

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, bad-gateway

Good day.

I have been working with Docker recently. Faced such a problem:
The administrative part of the site is working fine, and the public part gives an error 502 bad gateway.

Here are the settings for my docker:

docker-kompose.yml (root folder):

```
version: '3'

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.14
        ports:
            - "${NGINX_HOST}:${NGINX_PORT}:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html:cached
            - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        depends_on: [php]
        env_file: .env
        restart: always

    php:
        build:
            context: docker/php
            args:
                TIMEZONE: ${TIMEZONE}
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html:cached
            - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:cached
            - ./docker/php/php-fpm.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/99-custom.conf:cached
        user: "${DOCKER_UID}"
        env_file: .env
        restart: always

docker-kompose.override.yml (root folder):

    version: '3'

services:
    markup:
        build: docker/markup
        user: "${DOCKER_UID}"
        ports:
            - "${MARKUP_PORT}:4000"
        volumes:
            - ./:/app:cached
        command: bash -c "npm install --no-save && bower install && gulp external"
        environment:
            NODE_ENV: "${MARKUP_ENV}"

.env file (root folder):

    COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=nrd

# "docker-compose.yml:docker-compose.prod.yml" for prod
# "docker-compose.yml:docker-compose.stage.yml" for stage
COMPOSE_FILE=

DOCKER_UID=1000
DOCKER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.1

# "develop" or "production"
MARKUP_ENV=develop
MARKUP_PORT=4000

# 0.0.0.0 for external access
NGINX_HOST=127.0.0.1
NGINX_PORT=80

TIMEZONE=Europe/Moscow
```

nginx.conf (folder docker/nginx/):

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log off;
    error_log /dev/null crit;
    client_max_body_size 1024M;
    client_header_buffer_size 4k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    map $http_x_forwarded_proto $fastcgi_https {
        default off;
        https on;
    }

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    server {
        root   /var/www/html;
        listen       80;
        server_name  _;

        access_log off;
        error_log /dev/null crit;
        charset utf-8;

        location ~ ^/(\.git|log|docker|\.env) {
            return 404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 7200;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 72000;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 32k;

            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https if_not_empty;
            fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_forwarded_for;
            include        fastcgi_params;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite  ^(.*)/index.php$  $1/ redirect;
            }
        }

        location / {
            index index.php index.html index.htm;

            if (!-e $request_filename){
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php last;
            }
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(xml|html|jpg|jpeg|gif|ttf|eot|swf|svg|png|ico|mp3|css|woff2?|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|dat|avi|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|wmv|mpeg|mpg|mp4|m4a|spx|ogx|ogv|oga|webm|weba|ogg|tbz|js)$ {
            expires 30d;
            access_log off;
        }
    }
}
```

.Dockerfile (folder docker/php):

```
# See https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.1/fpm/Dockerfile
FROM php:7.1-fpm
ARG TIMEZONE

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openssl \
    git \
    zlibc \
    zlib1g \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    unzip

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN mkdir /.composer/ && chmod 777 /.composer/

# Set timezone
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TIMEZONE} /etc/localtime && echo ${TIMEZONE} > /etc/timezone
RUN printf '[PHP]\ndate.timezone = "%s"\n', ${TIMEZONE} > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/tzone.ini
RUN "date"

# Type docker-php-ext-install to see available extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql gd

# Install memcached extension
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y libmemcached11 libmemcachedutil2 build-essential libmemcached-dev libz-dev \
  && pecl install memcached \
  && echo extension=memcached.so >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini \
  && apt-get remove -y build-essential libmemcached-dev libz-dev \
  && apt-get autoremove -y \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /tmp/pear

RUN docker-php-ext-install intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache
RUN docker-php-ext-install soap

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends default-libmysqlclient-dev

RUN apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

WORKDIR /var/www/html

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

php.ini (folder docker/php):

```
[PHP]
short_open_tag = On
upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 250M
display_errors = Off
memory_limit = 1024M
max_execution_time = 60

[mbstring]
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
mbstring.func_overload = 2
```

php-fpm.conf (folder docker/php):

```
[www]
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 10
access.format = "%{REMOTE_ADDR}e - %u %t \"%m %{REQUEST_URI}e%Q%q\" %s %{miliseconds}dms %{megabytes}MM %C%%"
;slowlog = /proc/self/fd/2
;request_slowlog_timeout = 2s

php_admin_value[error_log] = /proc/self/fd/2
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

.Dockerfile (folder docker/markup):

```
    FROM node:10.13

RUN npm install -g gulp bower
RUN echo '{ "allow_root": true }' > /root/.bowerrc

RUN mkdir /.npm && mkdir /.config && mkdir /.cache && mkdir /.local && chmod 777 /.npm && chmod 777 /.config && chmod 777 /.cache && chmod 777 /.local

EXPOSE 4000

WORKDIR /app/markup
```

Please help, I do not understand what is the matter. Today everything worked fine, I did not touch the settings anywhere, I did not change the passwords anywhere. The public part of my local project just started giving 502 errors

Using Docker for Windows.